# Is 10K full nodes enough to bitcoin to avoid 51% attack?

Tags: bitcoin-core, nodes, full-node, majority-attack

As I know bitcoin has about 10K full nodes. And the question is in my mind is that: This number is not huge! If someone has 6K servers, Can control the bitcoin via 51% attack?

I was thinking if bitcoin had millions of nodes everything was ok but 10K is enough? What is the magic here that people trust bitcoin with 10K nodes?

Comment: Note that it's not about the number of full nodes but the computing power that can influence such an attack

Comment: I know, But that full nodes are not special powerful computers. I know it costs too much but I'm thinking if someone want to destroy bitcoin, It seems it's possible. Just need a few thousands PC's with good GPU. I mean "someone" like Russia, China or... they have that money and power

Comment: @Fcoder you are confusing 'network full nodes' with 'miners'. Running 10k full nodes has nothing to do with a 51% attack. GPUs are useless when mining bitcoin, specialized ASIC hardware is required.

Comment: A few thousand PCs with GPUs will not even make a dent in the total hashrate. 10000 GPUs, assuming the best available hardware, can hash at around 10 Thash/s. The global hashrate is approximately a million times more than that.